# Use jquery mouseover to show status from callback

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to use jquery to use a callback in a div and show the full text in another div?  Currently I have in the right div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$.post("status.php?_="+ $.now(), {day : "<?php echo $day;?>"}, function(upcoming){
$(".ticker").html(upcoming);
}),
"html"
}, 45000);
});
```

And I need something like:

```
$(".view").hover(function(){
$("#left").load("a.php");
});

<div id="left">
<div class="show">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="ticker">  
    </div>
</div>
```

My php spits back html: `<a href="" class="view">EventID</a>`

What I want to do is hover over the hyper link and have the full status shown in .show
I know I'll have to do a query with the event number, but my search in doing this comes up empty.  As always, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("body").on("hover", ".view", function(){
   $("#left").load("a.php");
});
```

As you're adding `.view` to DOM after page load i.e dynamically so, you need delegate event handler for dynamic element using **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**.

And instead of `body` you can use any parent selector of `.view` which is `static-element`.

Comment: I could have spent all day reading that question and not figured out that's what he's asking.

Comment: @thecodeparadox one more thing, it works great and there's a but here, using the hover the div left stays open with the info, should I use mouseover and mouseout?  It updates as I move down the list of events, but I'd like to disappear if I'm not hovered over a link